# how to get the value of a variable from save method

Tags: apex

I'm getting value of billing.billingfirstname in save method.Now I need to pass this value into another method....How can I get it.here is the code

```
 @future(callout=true)
 public static void sendEmail(string emailcontentbody,string template,string useremail,string textname){
  Messaging.singleEmailMessage email1 = new Messaging.singleEmailMessage();
  Invoice_Setting__c SettingsRec = [select SiteUrl__c from Invoice_Setting__c limit 1 ];
          string record = Settingsrec.SiteUrl__c; 
   *record+='?fname1='+billing.billingfirstName;*
  email1.setplaintextbody(textname+record);
       email1.setSubject('Response');
       email1.setToAddresses(new string[] {useremail});
         Messaging.sendEmailResult[] res = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[]{email1});
       system.debug('resulttt'+res);
}
```

How do I pass the value of `billing.billingfirstName` which I got from save method into record.

Comment: You want to pass it on URL or store in the record .

Comment: need to pass it in the url (say http://example-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/site?fname1=test)

Comment: Why are you having as an email.Please explain background

Comment: whenever save method is excecuted need to send an email of a siteurl in which this siteurl should consist of my billing.billingfirstname.Hope you understood

Comment: If this is the valid URL generated then you van hyperlink in your mail and send .

Comment: How can I do it...Can you be more clear please...

Comment: Send the link as the body in the email.The body will be your string with href and anchor tag.

Comment: You're looking for a way to send a url in the email Body? Or something else ? Not very clear. Maybe you could elaborate a little Aruna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apex [PageReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm) class is useful for building up and manipulating URLs.

You could try something like:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void sendEmail(string emailcontentbody,string template,string useremail,string textname){

    // missing code that creates the billing object

    Invoice_Setting__c SettingsRec = [select SiteUrl__c from Invoice_Setting__c limit 1 ];
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(SettingsRec.SiteUrl__c);
    Map<String, String> params = pageRef.getParameters();
    params.add('fname1', billing.billingfirstName);
    string urlForEmail = pageRef.getUrl();

    Messaging.singleEmailMessage email1 = new Messaging.singleEmailMessage();
    email1.setPlainTextBody(textname + '\n\n' +
                            record);
    email1.setSubject('Response');
    email1.setToAddresses(new string[] {useremail});
    Messaging.sendEmailResult[] res = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[]{email1});
}
```

If you want the URL to be a hyperlink use `setHtmlBody` rather than `setPlainTextBody`.